# Is There a limit memory usage on JVM?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I want to know if is there a limit memory usage that can I set to JVM, I know 32-bits OS I can't set over than 2G, but on 64-bits OS, can I set 32G, 64G, 128G, infinite?

Will this change make diference or more than a value will it not matter?

Comment: Which JVM version?

Comment: Your JVM heap needs to fit within main memory, ideally one NUMA region which means with today's tech that's around 1 TB.